# How to delete rows from a different tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a parent table with collection of IDs, how to transferred this collection to other tables in a block WHERE for deletion?
example:

```
select id from table_a <- it's collection of ids.
delete from table_b where table_b.ad_id in (COLLECTION_OF_IDS_FROM_PREVIOS_SQL_SCRIPT)
delete from table_c where table_c.ad_id in (COLLECTION_OF_IDS_FROM_PREVIOS_SQL_SCRIPT)
...
```

there is no possibility to cascade deletion

I find solution

```
delete from table_b where table_b.ad_id in (select id from table_a)
...
```

how to optimize this solution?

Comment: Consider ON DELETE CASCADE foreign keys instead.

Comment: Also, this is an excellent case to use SQL *transactions.*  `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, then issue the series of SQL commands necessary to accomplish the transfer, then `COMMIT`.  (If something goes wrong, `ROLLBACK`.)  When you do this, then, from the point-of-view of any other user, "either *everything* happened at once, or *nothing* did."  (They will not see "intermediate states.")  Use `try..except` logic in your programming to ensure that a `ROLLBACK` happens if a bug occurs.

Comment: @jarlh i can't execute this operation for fk

Answer (score 1):

After brief reflection, I want to bump my previous reply to an "answer."

A situation like this – in any SQL database – is an ideal case for SQL "transactions."  A transaction is an *atomic* unit of work.  First you `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, then you issue one or more SQL commands.  When you finish, `COMMIT`.  Or, if something goes wrong, `ROLLBACK`.

*(Use `try..except` logic in your programming to ensure that `ROLLBACK` occurs if an exception is raised.)*

Other users of the database system will either see that *"all* of the changes that you made occurred, *instantaneously,"* when you `COMMIT`,  or, that *"none* of them did."  Other users will not see the database as being in any "intermediate states," even though you do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using a [data modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
with id_list as (
   select id 
   from table_a 
   where ...
), delete_b as (
   delete from table_b 
   where table_b.ad_id in (select * from id_list)
)
delete from table_c 
where table_c.ad_id in (select * from id_list);
```

This can also be used to delete rows from a hierarchy of tables that are linked with foreign keys (essentially a "manual" cascading delete).

```
with remove_root as (
   delete from root_table
   where ....
   returning pk_column
), delete_child_1 as (
  delete from child_one
  where root_id in (select * from remove_root)
  returning pk_column
), delete_child_2 as (
  delete from child_one
  where root_id in (select * from remove_root)
)
delete from grand_child
where child_one_id in (select * from delete_child_1);
```